# Why does const int size give ambiguity error in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

This code throws an ambiguity error when I try to run it

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int size = 100;

class items{
 int itemList[size];
};
```

But when I replace size with something else it works fine, for example

```
const int x = 100;
class items{
  int itemList[x];
};
```

Whats the reason for not accepting size as a name? My textbook uses size in an example

Comment: That's an example of why `using namespace std` is inadvisable

Comment: See [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: This question is a clear example of name collisions when using `using namespace std`; now SO users have a concrete question to point to when saying "don't do that because..." instead of a hypothetical one.

Comment: You could read the error completely, stopping reading on error titles is a bad habit. From the complete error, you would see the origin of another `size`.

Comment: @Casey "now SO users have a concrete question to point to when saying "don't do that because..."" - We already had one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: `size` is an identifier in namespace `std` (specifically, a family of functions named `std::size()` which give the number of elements in various standard containers and raw arrays). Although not required, implementations are not forbidden from declaring `std::size()` in `<iostream>`. With `using namespace std`, those functions are considered as candidates when the identifier `size` is used (in some contexts) which can cause ambiguity. If you insist on `using namespace std` (some people advocate never using it) you must manage various consequences, including potential name collisions like this.

Comment: @Casey - It's not all that concrete, since `std:size()` is not required to be declared in `<iostream>` (and not forbidden either).   The code as given will therefore build with some compilers (and their libraries) but not others.

Comment: I've been using this example for several years now.

Comment: *"an ambiguity error"* -- If you do not understand the error message, you should not paraphrase it. Paraphrasing typically drops important details. Copy the entire message (including notes) into the question, formatted in a code block. Those notes are important because they list exactly which symbols contribute to the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You pulled every name from the `std` namespace into the global namespace when you did `using namespace std;` at global scope. That means you also pulled in `std::size` as `size`, so now your own `const int size` clashes with `std::size`.
Don't do `using namespace std;` it causes more problems than the typing it saves (ohh, and in any case; *never* use `using namespace ...;` in a *header* file - in a source file it can be ok, especially if restricted to a function, but in a header it will just pollute every source file that includes it, don't ever do that).

See also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)